# Factoring Polynomials and primality testing in R[x]

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Say I want to factor a polynomial in R[X], but this polynomial has no roots in R. How exactly do you go about factoring it?

For example, if we have $f(x) = x^4 + 16$, this factors into $(x^2 - 2\sqrt{2}x + 4)(x^2 + 2\sqrt{2}x + 4)$. However, I was only able to come to this by sort of playing around with numbers (guess and check). Is there a systematic approach to knowing if a polynomial is prime in R[x] and if it isn't how to go about factoring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the coefficients are real numbers. Any real polynomial factors as
$$ c(x - r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_t)(x^2 - 2 a_1 x + a_1^2 + b_1^2)(x^2 - 2 a_2 x + a_2^2 + b_2^2)\cdots(x^2 - 2 a_u x + a_u^2 + b_u^2)   $$ because the non-real roots come in conjugate pairs. This does not mean there is any nice way to write the roots.